# Write files scp with chilkat lib

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, sftp, scp, raspberry-pi3

I'm using a raspberry pi to store some files.
I used Chilkat SSH/SCP lib and is working.
I also have a C++ program that generate a file using ascii (0-256) chars.
If I write the file to my local disk with fwrite it will write correctly but if I try to append to a file using SCP it will only write some parts.
I think that is because of the control chars (0-31).

Edit:
In the source.cpp:

```
while (!feof(filename))
{
size_t read = fread(&buf, 1, max_array, filename);
                    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < read; i++)
                    {
                        char rdn = GetRandom_Soft();
                        num[i] = rdn;
                        buf[i] = buf[i] + rdn;
                    }
                    fwrite(&num, sizeof(char), read, filename2);
                    s7c.WriteKey((char *)rasp_file.c_str(), buf);
}
```

Then I have a func "s7c.WriteKey" with Chilkat lib:

```
int s7c_SFTP::WriteKey(char * filename, char * c)
{
    if (s7c_SFTP::bloked) return -1;
if (!s7c_SFTP::scp.UploadString(filename, c, "ansi"))
{
    cout << "[ERROR] Erro sending to device!" << endl;
    return -2;
}
return 0;
}
```

And "GetRandomSoft":

```
char otp_samega7cattac::GetRandom_Soft()
{
    return rand() % 256;
}
```

Result:
For example you have a input of a 1Mb file so the file genareted localy will have the same size and he have so that part works, but the file generated in the raspberry will be smaller and the size isn't the same every time I run the program, so I think that is because when I sum what I read with the random number if is between 0 and 31 the lib dont write it.

Original file (61 bytes):

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvyxwzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVYXWZ123456789
```

Local File (work! 61 bytes):

```
.覦 {5・&｣jN)sｴｘG悵ｺrp焏Ь断・ﾑｲﾉη`WP>・|auﾛ・lﾂn
```

Rasp (nope, 20 bytes) #1 try:

```
ÿ’_dN'–^N%eÖµ€%¤ŸAÞ
```

Rasp (almost, 58 bytes)#2 try:

```
vI³áœ€Ot×¼˜ã%»n%4>´F´@™UÌ¦Ü±ÑÔÔ³«¥”ó[Ó»¦
(l¡øS¦G
```

Can exist some kind of chars this textbox don't acept so I put the sizes!

Edit 2:

Now I have sure the problem are the control chars!!!

I made a test. If the sum of the random char and the buffer is lower then 31 I especify the `buf[i] = 'a';` And the sizes matches!!!

But I have no idea how to write control chars in the raspberry pi because I need all chars (0-255).

Comment: Show us your code! + *"some parts"* - What parts? Show us an example of file hex dump before and after write.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Ok, I will add some